# Basic Static Dropdown Coldfusion

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, coldfusion, dropdown

I'm new to coldfusion and I am attempting to create a static dropdown list for the user to select a value and store it in a variable. The error is: ***Element DROPDOWN.VALUE is undefined in FORM.***

This is what my code looks like:

```
<cfform method='post'>
     <cfselect name='dropDown' default='blue'>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="white">White</option>
     </cfselect>
</cfform>
<cfset color = #form.dropDown.value#>
```

Comment: The form scope is not available until you submit the form.

Comment: Dan is right - but you would also should drop `.value` at the end of that line - if and when you do process the form. `#form.dropDown#` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `cfform` and like Dan said the form scope is not available until you've submitted the form

```
<form method='post'>
  <select name='dropDown'>
    <option value="blue" selected>Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
  </select>
</form>
<cfset color = structKeyExists(form, 'dropDown') ? form.dropDown : 'blue'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The FORM scope isn't available until the form has been submitted using POST.

What you want to do can be done one of two ways, neither of which require the use of cfform, and in fact I would suggest that you not use cfform to begin with. The HTML form syntax is quite simple to use and ultimately will make you a better developer in that the front end code that you write doesn't rely on ColdFusion to function. The featureset of the CF UI stuff (cfform, cfwindow, etc.) had its place many years ago when it was released, but the world of web development has made significant strides since then and this is no longer the best way to handle UI. Thing such as jQuery and Bootstrap help great with things like layout and making things look nice.

Anyway, to your question, there are two possible ways to do what you want to do, depending on exactly what you want to do. If you are trying for instance change the color of the background immediately every time the user selects a different color, you will want to look into using javascript as ColdFusion code is executed completely before the client sees the page but JavaScript is run in the client's browser. jQuery (a JavaScript framework) will greatly simplify doing this.

If however you just want to run some Coldfusion code based solely on the previous submission of the form to the page, then Matt Busche's answer is exactly the way to go. Two things about the example he gave, the `cfset` doesn't have to be after the form, it can be anywhere in the page since it will be acting on the data submitted in from the previous form submission. The other is that he is using ternary operators in the `coset` (which look really weird and confusing if you have never seen them before, read more about those here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1643-learning-coldfusion-9-the-ternary-operator.htm) to check if the dropdown value exists from a previous form submission (which it wouldn't any time the page loads for any reason other than the form being submitted) and then sets a default if it doesn't exist. Everything before the question mark is the boolean check, then the colon splits the two possible places for the value (use the form variable it the `strctKeyExists` is true, use the hard coded value of blue if it doesn't).